# (discord.py) What is the correct way of checking if a message contains an element from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a profanity filter for my bot. I allowed server admins to make their own list of bad words which my bot uses for their server. In the `on_message` function I used this code to check if a user's message contains a word from the filter:

```
file = open(f"configs/antiswearvalues/customantiswear/{message.guild.id}.txt")

res = [ele for ele in file.read() if (ele in message.content)]

if bool(res):
    await message.channel.send("you did a bad. time for the boot.")
```

The problem is the bot still said `you did a bad. time for the boot.` even if the message contained a snippet from the elements and not an entire element.

So if the list was `['omg', 'crap', 'hell']`, the bot would still warn the user if their message contained `h` or `cr` because `hell` and `crap` contain those.

My question is: **How can I make my bot properly check if a user's message contains an element from a list?**

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `file.readlines()` which returns a list of each line, rather than `file.read()`? Actually, it would be helpful to see this text file.

Comment: @dantechguy the text file only contains the list (for now, each discord server has its own file) so it wouldnt matter which one i used. the text file is literally just `['omg', 'crap', 'hell']`

Comment: Well then you're going to need to parse that list, because right now `file.read()` returns the whole file as a string. But you could use `readlines()` and change your file to have each word on its own line: `omg\ncrap\nhell`

Comment: You are iterating over a string. Not a list. It does not see `['omg', 'crap', 'hell']` It sees `"['omg', 'crap', 'hell']"`. So when you are iterating you do not get `"omg"`, `"crap"` and `"hell"`. You get `"["`, `"'"`, `"o"`, `"m"`, ...

Comment: @TinNguyen Yep that's the problem. I converted the string into a proper list and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). Getting a word blacklist will be way easier than parsing a txt file without using any library:

Your json file (eg. blacklist.json):

```
['omg', 'crap', 'hell']
```

Your python code:

```py
from json import loads

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open("blacklist.json", "r"):
        data = loads(file.read())
    for word in data:
        if word in message.content:
            await message.channel.send("you did a bad. time for the boot.")
    return
```

Your code isn't working as intended because you didn't parsed your file data, you were exploring a string, not a list.

Comment: Just a note: you can also parse a text file as a one column .csv file if each blacklisted word is on a new line. You'll still need 'import csv' but it could be simpler for end users.